# sql Server 2008 R2(64 bit) and oracle 10g linked server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, linked-server

we are migrating from our old SQL server 2005 (32 bit) to a windows server 2008 R2 with SQL server 2008 installed on it (64 bit) . in the old server we had a linked server to our other server which was oracle 10g ,can some one please tell me how can I create the linked server on this new server as I couldn't find the data provider for oracle on sql server 2008 and I tried many of oracle solutions but none of them could install on server 2008 (failed at very first step checking for OS version) .
please tell me how can I install the provider for oracle and where shall I download it from .
thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the way how to do it which I would explain it here as I think other people may have this problem :

Use the correct and only certified install source from here

Unpack and open a command prompt in the "..\database" directory where the "setup.exe" is located. Run the following command: setup.exe -ignoreSysprereqs

Wait for the OUI windows and continue with your preferences selections. When the OUI prerequisites window appear it will come with the following error:

INFO: The user has manually verified 'Checking operating system requirements ...' INFO: Checking CertifiedVersions This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the Oracle software is certified on the current O/S. INFO: Expected result: One of 5.0,5.1,5.2,6.0 Actual Result: 6.1 Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Failed <<<<

Select the checkbox to bypass the error and continue installation

and something else that you have to do before creating the linked server is : go to sql server management studio open server objects\linked servers\providers right click on oraoledb.oracle and the properties in properties check the box for Allow inprocess.

it's all ready now use oraoledb.oracle to create the linked server .